# What is the probability of escaping from jail if....?

Tags: probability

*Disclaimer: The story given below is purely fictional and does not, in any way, relate to a prison break.* :P

> Four roads lead away from a jail. A prisoner is trying to escape from
>   the jail and selects one road at random. If road A is selected, the
>   probability of escaping is (1/8), or road B it is (1/6), for road C it
>   is (1/4) and for road D it is (9/10). What is the probability that the
>   prisoner will succeed in escaping from the jail.

Now, the book gives the formula as follows:

P(E) = $p1p1' + p2p2' + p3p3'+p4p4'$ where
P(E) is probability of escape,
$p1$ is the probability of choosing road A.

What I would like to ask is.. what is $p1'$ ?

*On the previous page it explains something about the 'theorem on total probability' in really shoddy terms. It is something related but  cannot understand what.*

Comment: @drhab Sorry, I had made a mistake. I edited the question. See it.

Comment: Note that the answers we're providing are based on interpolating the only thing that it'd make sense for $p1'$ to be. Your book most likely defines $p1'$ somewhere you've simply missed; try rereading the surrounding text.

Comment: @user2357112 See the answer to the question :) I explained what it is. I did not miss it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p1'$ is the chance of escaping through road A, so $1/8$ in your example (because its random). $p2'$ would be the chance of escaping though road B (so $1/6$), et cetera.

Anyhow, $P(E)$ consists of the summation of two factors: $p_n$ being the chance to pick the road (randomly, so $1/4$) and $p_n'$ the chance to escape through that road.

Comment: It says .. $p1'$ is $p(E|A)$ and has value $\frac{1}{8}$ Don't know how they got that.

Comment: I see your edited your question: I will edit my answer :)

Comment: +1 for rapid emergency response. It is exam time, mate. :D

Comment: Hehe, I know. Not for me, luckily enough

Comment: How does it come to 1/8 ? :)

Comment: That is stated in the question: The chance to escape through road A is 1/8

Comment: @LittleChild: It's given to you right in the problem description: "If road A is selected, the probability of escaping is (1/8)"

Comment: aaaaah okay. So the probability of selecting any road is one out of 4. I see. p(A) = 1/4 . My bad. Exam stress. :p

Comment: oh gawd... me so dumb! x(

Comment: Exam stress. Chill a little bit, it will probably be more effective ;)

Comment: haha yeah! have a good day, mate! I'll probably be flooding more questions in the coming days. :D

Answer (score 1):

Set up a tree of possibilities, where each branching point is a decision (take road 1, 2, 3, or 4, then escape or not for each), each edge is labeled with the probability of taking that option . Mark the ends (leaves) that interest you (escape successful), for each of them compute the probability by multiplying probabilities along the path from the root, add all up. Rigorous justification of this is quite simple.

This is overkill in your case, the tree is just two steps deep; but having an orderly, uniform technique to handle more complex situations that helps avoiding forgetting or duplicating one of a myriad of cases is valuable.